# @IonicPage decorator requires a module per page?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a lot of pages, organizad in folders, I want to have only one module file per each folder and not per each page, its that possible? what should I put in imports? can I use deep linking?

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ActivityDetailsPage,
    HobbySelectionPage,
    ConversationModalPage,
    ParticipantsModalPage,
    AddGuestsPage
  ],
  imports: [],
  exports: [
    ActivityDetailsPage,
    HobbySelectionPage,
    ConversationModalPage,
    ParticipantsModalPage,
    AddGuestsPage
  ],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

At first if you want to use `@ionicPage()` decorator for `ExamplePage` (example.ts). You need ExamplePageModule like given below

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {IonicPageModule} from 'ionic-angular';
import {ExamplePage} from './example';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [ ExamplePage],
  imports: [ IonicPageModule.forChild(ExamplePage) ]
})

export class ExamplePageModule {}
```

You do not need import on `app.modul.ts` if u use as a deep link such as like `'ExamplePage'` not as `ExamplePage`

Comment: If u need additional info please specify.

Comment: So I need a module per page? can not group them?

Comment: Generally u are true.